# why am I getting a PROTOCOL ERROR from OkHttp request?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, request, okhttp

I've been searching for awhile on this topic. I'm trying to send data to my backend server using `OkHttp`. However, I am getting this error:

`okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException:` `stream was reset:PROTOCOL_ERROR`

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val response = client.newCall(
    Request.Builder()
           .addHeader("Authorization:", "Bearer $firebaseToken")
           .url("https://someURL/"+ podcastId.toString())
           .build())
    .execute()
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with the `URL` or my `Authorization` header? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest trying the API from a postman or any other REST API client, It seems the stream returned by the API request is not proper.

Answer (score 10):

I solved a similar problem by restricting the request to use HTTP 1, see:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
```